# react native as soon as is array.push done

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way how to catch when is array.push function done? I get data from Firebase database then I push data to array (which is state). Unfortunately as I noticed it changes my state once per every item.

Check [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuLNi.png) for better understanding

[image: screen]

I have 2 objects in database.

there is code:

```
componentWillMount(){
    const self = this;
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
    const ref = rootRef.child("MyTeams");
    let teamsArr = [];
    ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            self.setState({TeamName: childSnapshot.val()});
            teamsArr.push(self.state.TeamName);
            self.setState({TeamsToMap: teamsArr});
            self.setState({Loaded: true});
            console.log('Here: ' + self.state.TeamsToMap);
        })
    })
        .catch((error) =>{
            alert(error.message);
        })
};


WriteTeams(navigation){
    if(this.state.TeamsToMap.length > 0 && this.state.Loaded === true){
        console.log('Somewhere: ' + this.state.TeamsToMap.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're looping over the snapshot, the array is modified many times. If you only want to print it after the modification are done: move the `console.log()` statement after the loop.

```
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        self.setState({TeamName: childSnapshot.val()});
        teamsArr.push(self.state.TeamName);
        self.setState({TeamsToMap: teamsArr});
        self.setState({Loaded: true});
    })
    console.log('Here: ' + self.state.TeamsToMap);
})
```

Since both `snapshot.forEach()` and `teamsArr.push()` are synchronous here, the `console.log()` will run after `teamsArr` has been fully populated.

Comment: Thanks for help! I moved self.setState({Loaded: true}) with console.log and problem is solved. It was really embarrassing mistake.